# Looking for a program to help keep track of Database updates

Tags: database, project-management

I've got a large database that needs to be updated/checked on a regular basis. Something similar to a preventative maintenance program. (Doesn't need to be connected to the database)

I can't give to much detail but lets say it's a database of multiple business inventories. I need a way to keep track of the last time a businesses inventory was checked, if it's currently being checked, and when it needs to be checked again (x amount of days after being checked last). Also need to know WHO was the last one to check it.

I've yet to find anything like this on the web. I'm not sure if this is something that already exists or something I'll have to develop my self.

Comment: It will greatly depend on what database system you're using, but if you can modify the DB then adding a couple of triggers that write changes to an audit table is relatively simple and doesn't requires anything external.